# ¿Como saber la semana completa del usuario con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como se puede saber la semana completa del usuario empezando desde el dia en el que este, por ejemplo si esta en el *29 de octubre del 2020* ( 29/10/2020 ) que me de ese dia y el siguiente (30/10/20) y el siguiente (31/10/2020) y el siguiente (01/11/2020) y asi hasta completar una semana completa.

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: @Einer si te soy sincero no ase mucho empece con javascript, hasta ahora solo tengo esto let fecha = new Date();
let fechaActual = fecha.getDate()+"/"+fecha.getMonth()+"/"+fecha.getFullYear(); 
solo tengo esto para saber el dia, mes y año

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esto puede ser de ayuda, mira lo primero que hago es usar el objeto `Date`, para poder hacer modificación de la fecha, luego dentro de un `for` voy recorriendo una semana para que pueda mostrarme los 7 días a partir de hoy por eso comienzo desde `0`.

Quedaría algo así:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();
for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
console.log(date.addDays(i));
}
```